# array = numpy.fromfile(fp, dtype=dtype, count=count) MemoryError in python 3.6 Spyder

Tags: numpy, python-3.6

On running this program st.py click[here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NKWJY1g8lcm4u8ty8TiCvTfP8EvEwJrs]
it shows memory error.

```
X=np.load('X.npy')

File "C:\Users\AB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py",          line 440, in load     pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\AB\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 704, in read_array

array = numpy.fromfile(fp, dtype=dtype, count=count)

MemoryError
```